# Setting up /29 public IP addresses on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, router, internet-connection

I've been banging my head on the router for days. Any help would be much appreciated.

My setup:
DSL static IP + /29

Modem connected to router connected to 2 PCs running Windows

What I need: Giving each PC a permanent unique public IP.

Let's say my static IP is 1.1.1.1 and subnet is 2.2.2.2.

My router's RouterBoard, and here's what I did (and failed):

1. Booted up the router with a clean config
2. PPP -> new PPPoE Client -> entered my user and pass -> chose ether1 as interface. 
   My static IP automatically showed up in the address list.
3. Bridge -> made new_bridge (didn't set anything else)
4. Bridge -> ports -> Added ether2, ether3, ether4 to new_bridge
5. IP -> Addresses -> Added 2.2.2.3/29 to new_bridge
6. IP -> Firewall -> input:accept; forward:accept

At this point, I no longer have Internet connection, and I go into Windows to change IPv4 properties:

- IP Address: 2.2.2.4
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248
- Default Gateway: 2.2.2.3
- Preferred DNS: 8.8.8.8
- Alternate DNS: 8.8.4.4

Still no Internet and no idea what to do. Would appreciate any hint to set me in the right direction.

Comment: nvm. Just fixed the problem by running winbox as admin.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer not a comment and mark it answered.

Comment: ok will do :)))

Comment: When we say "mark it answered", we mean "click on the checkmark to the left of the answer" and *not* "edit the question to say that it's been answered."  Since you're answering your own question and you have very low rep, that option (clicking the checkmark) might not be available to you right away (you might have to wait a few hours or even a couple of days).  But, before you do that, please edit your answer to make it approximately as detailed as the question, so that it can be useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm. Just fixed the problem by running winbox as admin.

edit: a more detailed answer: I ran "winbox.exe" as administrator in Win8.1. Did everything else exactly like I described in my question. Problem solved. This is not the first time I "solved" something simply by running a program as admin.

Comment: Can you go into more detail? We'd like this to be useful to others who might come across in the future.

Comment: Sure. I ran "winbox.exe" as administrator in Win8.1, did not change anything else, and I no longer had problems. This is as detailed as I can be...